# Proof for ∨ distributing over →

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm am stuggling to prove the following:

x ∨ ( y → z ) ≡ ( x ∨ y ) → ( x ∨ z )

After making a truth table, I know that disjunction distributes over implication but I am failing to prove the above equation using theorems.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What exactly can you use?

Comment: We have 70 theorems such as: 
"≡ associative/symmetric/identity" etc. 
"∨ associative/symmetric" etc. 
"The Absorbtion Laws" 
"∨/∧" etc.
"→ reflexive" etc.
"De Morgan's Laws"
"→ to ¬∨"
"contra-positive"
"Modus Ponens"

etc etc....

Comment: OK. I would start with the RHS, go from it to $\color{blue}{((\neg x\land \neg y)\lor x)}\lor z$ and now distribute the blue part. The rest should come easily.

Comment: Ok, I have reduced it down to (¬y ∨ x) ∨ z, but I can't seem to get it anywhere nearer to the LHS. Using "∨ symmetric" can I re-arrange this to  (¬y ∨ z) ∨ x and then distribute this? Even if I do this I still can't reach the LHS.

Comment: Surely you have commutativity of $\lor$. Also $\neg p \lor q\equiv p\to q$?

Comment: Yes I have both of them. "Commutativity of ∨" is named "∨ symmetric" in the theorems I have. I have reduced it down to ( ¬y ∨ x) ∨ (z ∨ x), but to reach the LHS I would need the negation outside of the brackets

Comment: You went backwards somewhere. From $(\neg y\lor z)\lor x$ it's two steps to get the LHS, namely the ones justified by the two rules in my previous comment.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't thinking straight for a few minutes! Thank you for your help. Just a side not on commutativity: If I have ¬y ∨ (z → x) ∧ x, I cannot change this to ¬y ∨ x ∧ (z → x) can I?

Comment: No problem. You can't even have $\neg y\lor (z\to x)\land x$. This formula is ill-formed, it needs parentheses.

Comment: @GitGud Would you mind transforming your comments into an answer?

Comment: @Workaholic I appreciate the comment and the effort to make the site even better. But I would actually mind, because the answer would just be ignored. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a full answer using [Git Gud](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55235/git-gud)'s approach, which is just sound advice: if you need to prove an equality or equivalence, then start at the most complex side and treat it as a simplification problem.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

And specifically for propositional logic, it is helpful to know that it is often helpful to expand $\;P \then Q\;$, and that there are three basic ways to do that: $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$, or $\;P \equiv P \land Q\;$, or $\;P \lor Q \equiv Q\;$.

So we start at the right hand side, and calculate as follows:
$$\calc
    (x \lor y) \then (x \lor z)
\op=\hint{expand $\;\then\;$ in the shortest way possible}
    \lnot (x \lor y) \lor x \lor z
\op=\hint{DeMorgan -- this looks like the simplest way to make progress}
    (\lnot x \land \lnot y) \lor x \lor z
\op=\hint{distribute $\;x\;$ over the left hand part -- brings the $\;x\;$'s together}
    ((\lnot x \lor x) \land (\lnot y \lor x)) \lor z
\op=\hint{excluded middle; simplify}
    \lnot y \lor x \lor z
\op=\hint{reorder disjuncts; re-introduce $\;\then\;$}
    x \lor (y \then z)
\endcalc$$
This completes the proof that $\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\then\;$.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following, $$
\begin{align}
x \lor ( y \to z ) 
&
\equiv 
x\lor(\lnot y\lor z) 
\\
&
\equiv
(x\lor \lnot y)\lor z
\\
&
\equiv
\big({\mathtt{T}}\land(x\lor \lnot y)\big)\lor z
\\
&
\equiv
\big((\lnot x\lor x)\land(x\lor \lnot y)\big)\lor z
\\
&
\equiv
\big(x\lor (\lnot x\land \lnot y)\big)\lor z
\\
&
\equiv
\big((\lnot x\land \lnot y)\lor x\big)\lor z
\\
&
\equiv
(\lnot x\land \lnot y)\lor (x\lor z)
\\
&
\equiv
\lnot(x\lor y)\lor (x\lor z)
\\
&
\equiv
( x \lor y ) \to ( x \lor z ).\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align}$$