# How does conjunction distribute over implication?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic

I've been given a sample paper in preparation for an exam, and this question is on it:

Prove that conjunction distributes over implication (ie. ∧ over ⟹). Use this to simplify X ∧ (Y ⟹ Z)

How would I go about it?

Comment: You could follow the method explained in [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492175/proof-for-%e2%88%a8-distributing-over-%e2%86%92?rq=1)

Comment: To me, the claim that $\land$ distributes over $\implies$ means that, for all $X,Y,Z$, we have that $X\land(Y\implies Z)$ equal (or rather logically equivalent) to $(X\land Y)\implies (X\land Z)$.  Unfortunately, that equivalence is not valid; it fails whenever $X$ is false, regardless of the truth values of $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: Maybe $X \land (Y \to Z) \equiv X \land (\lnot Y \lor Z) \equiv (X \land \lnot Y) \lor (X \land Z) \equiv \lnot (\lnot X \lor Y) \lor (X \land Z) \equiv (\lnot X \lor Y) \to (X \land Z)$.